# Cinnamon not loading properly, maybe Gnome instead?

Tags: gnome, cinnamon

I installed Cinnamon, rebooted, selected Cinnamon at login but I don't think it's loading properly.  I cant seem to get the Mint menu that all the online installation guides have screenshots of. I wonder if I'm even running Cinnamon or it's just the Gnome classic interface? Here's a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

I am running an Acer Aspire Revo - R3610 which uses a Nvidia Ion GPU.  I've tried both the current and current-updates drivers, and I'm running Ubuntu 12.04LTS x86

Comment: Can you run Unity 3D or Gnome-Shell?  If you cannot then I suspect this is either a graphics card and/or a graphics driver issue.  Perhaps if you can add those details into your question?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like gnome-classic to me.

At the log in screen you should be able to click the little circle next to where you put in your password and a list of options will drop down. One of them should actually say  the word Cinnamon.

Cinnamon need graphics acceleration, so if you select Cinnamon with out the right graphics, you will end up in Gnome fallback mode.

Comment: Yes, it does...